# Find case sensitive words in text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file need to search it may be uppercase or lowercase letters in file using python

Comment: What did you tried? Did you read pydoc?

Comment: I don't understand your question. are you looking for uppercase letters in your file ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should spent more time writing the question, if you expect us to invest time in answering it. Nevertheless, from what I understand you are looking for something like this:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[0], "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        for chr in row:
            if chr.isupper():
                print chr, "uppercase"
            else:
                print chr, "lowercase"
```